# Checking length of a string pointer in Go

Tags: pointers, go

How do I go about finding the length of a string pointer which comes from a struct. Currently I am writing unit tests and want to see whether a string pointer is less than 250 characters. If r is my and myString is a string pointer.

This code is not valid:

```
if len(r.myString) > 256 {
    return ErrStringTooLong
}
```

Comment: String pointers are always the same size--the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You should explain why your code is not correct, and which error message you get. If it is a pointer to a string, you should dereference it by asterix *

```
len(*r.myString)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can access an object with a star before pointer variable name for eg `len(*r.myString)`

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/lLwKtOh7NCz)